# How to pass command line parameters to java app in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a command line Java app and I like to debug the app.
Especially, I like to debug the processing of the command line arguments.

An example of the usage of the command line app:
CmdLine -p //updates products
CmdLine -c //updates customers

In NetBeans (8.0.2) you can define command line parameters as part of the 'Run' configuration in the 'arguments' box. That works fine. However, these 'Arguments' are not used when you start a debugging session. I recall that there used to be a 'Debug' configuration, but this is not there anymore.
[image]

The question is:
"How can I specify Arguments for a Debugging session in NetBeans?".

Comment: Make sure you are debugging the project and not the file. The arguments won't be used even if you use "Run File"

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

[image: debud in Netbeans]

This panel appears after running debug from menu